# Importing users to AD with CSV, cannot get some fields to work

Tags: active-directory, powershell, csv

Been trying to build a CSV file to import users into Active Directory.  I can get everything to populate, except for E-mail, Password, and Enabling the user.  Just using this cmdlet in Powershell.

```
Import-CSV "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\adimport.csv" | new-ADUser
```

This is what my CSV looks like.

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZPUb.png)

For some reason the E-Mail field in the General tab won't fill.  I'm also not sure what column header to use to enable the profile, and I think password is userPassword, right?

Is there something i'm doing wrong that the E-Mail field won't fill in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rename field in csv from `mail` to `EmailAddress`

New-ADUser accepts a property of `EmailAddress`, but not `mail`.  Some of these correspond to an AD attribute, but not all.

New-ADUser
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx

Comment: That was it, didn't see that anywhere in the Attribute Editor and everything I had read said to use `mail`

Comment: You can try: `get-AdUser -filter 'samAccountName -like "Administrator"' -properties *|Get-Member` to view all properties of the object

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much.  Most of the stuff I was reading was from Server 2008, so maybe they changed that property name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is list of all Get-aduser default and extended properties.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx